# How to reset UIWebView's zoom? I'm already using scalesPagesToFit = YES;

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming, reset

I've been looking for the past week for the answer to this question.

I have a UIWebView, inside of a UIScrollView. Everything works great, but I want the content of the UIWebView to reset its zoom, when the orientation changes.

In the HTML inside the UIWebView, I set the width of the viewport (w/ a meta tag) to "device-width" and then on the Obj-C side, I set the scalesPagesToFit = YES;

I've tried resetting the zoom with javascript; by replacing the meta tags in runtime; reloading; accessing the UIScrollView inside of the UIWebView; etc...

but with no success.

Any of you gods know a workaround?

The only one I can think off is to recreate the UIWebViews every time we change the orientation, but that makes them flash to white whilst rendering content, which looks terrible :(

Any thoughts?

Many thanks,
Andre

Comment: Maybe the trick is in rebuilding the webviews? I've tried it, but they flash white, because of that moment in time where they lose their content, so it doesn't look great. Any other workarounds?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I think the mobile version of the wikipedia site does this. You could take a peak at it's html / javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just guessing here and haven't tried, but AFAIK a UIWebView has a UIScrollView child. So one should be able to do:

```
for (UIScrollView *scroll in [myWebView subviews]) {
    // Make sure it really is a scroll view and reset the zoom scale.
    if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:)])
        [scroll setZoomScale:1.0];
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this would pass the App Store's approval, or is it a private API? Cheers, Andre

Comment: This should be perfectly fine. I've seen an article that uses the same technique to switch off the bouncing of the view when it reaches the end. Only public APIs are used here so nothing for Apple to complain about. If Apple decides to change UIWebView to not use a UIScrollView child any more this code won't crash, it just won't reset the zoom any more.

Comment: Cool. Just so you know, I'd tried this code before and it didn't work. I've found that to make it work (in my case) you need to first replace the meta tags in the HTML, to change the viewport's maximum-scale back to 1.0, and then call the setZoomScale.

Comment: I have noticed that changing the meta viewport is only working if the user hasn't changed the zoom by pinching the screen. As soon as he changed it manually, this code is needed on the native side, after having reset the viewport. As @thieryb said in another answer, there is a shorter way now : `[webView.scrollView setZoomScale:1.0];`

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 5+ you have access to scrollView.
Just do:

[webView.scrollView setZoomScale:1.0];

Comment: it works well, thanks. this is way simpler than the for loop. but as @Andre said in a comment on the accepted answer, you need to first replace the meta tags in the HTML to change the viewport's maximum-scale back to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically this is the only way I could find to accomplish it: (specify your own sizes if you wish, i was attempting to zoom out after typing into a form field)

```
UIScrollView *sv = [[webViewView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[sv zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sv.contentSize.width, sv.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Downscaling wasn't working properly when using

```
[[[webView subviews] lastObject] setZoomScale:0.25];
```

The quality of the images being downscaled on the page was awful. Doing:

```
[[[webView subviews] lastObject] setZoomScale:0.25 animated:YES];
```

Fixed it. So that last line is the one you could use.

webView was subclassed of a UIWebView which lies on some IB file. I didn't use the Viewport at all. I find that one should pick by either doing this from the Cocoa Touch side or use JS.

I used:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

I wonder if there's a way of resetting the scalesPageToFit.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from Captnwalker1's answer, I came up with this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if(toInterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        currentScrollView = [[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        [currentScrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, currentScrollView.contentSize.width, currentScrollView.contentSize.height) animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        currentScrollView = [[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        [currentScrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, currentScrollView.contentSize.width, currentScrollView.contentSize.height) animated:NO];
    }
}
```

So load your webview image, and the image will reset it's size when rotated.